# A young boy with telekinetic abilities

Tags: identify-this-movie

I am trying to find a film which I saw more than 15 years ago. I'm (almost) sure it was European and the title was translated as something like 'The Young Wizard (or Magician)'. The film was about a young, pre-pubescent boy who discovered he had various telekinetic abilities; the usual troubles at school, a girl was involved.

Somewhere near the end the school psychologist explained that as the boy was getting closer to puberty, he was going to lose the abilities.

The end scene was how his best friend (or him?) performed some 'ordinary' magic tricks on a scene, the audience applauded and in a final 'magical' act the boy made confetti fall from the ceiling.

I'm quite positive that it was not a horror movie, but rather what we call 'family movie'.

Comment: You say "translated as"...was this in a different language?  Do you know what language?

Comment: I suspect it might be either Czech, Austrian or German, but I can't swear to it. The film was broadcast on TV and I watched it dubbed in Bulgarian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a film from 1987 that fits your descriptions: A troubled boy discovers his telekinetic abilities.

It is a co-production between Poland and Canada, hence the original titles are 'Cudowne dziecko', 'Le jeune magicien' and 'The Young Magician'.

Here is the [IMDb link](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0092806/).

Especially using the Polish title, you will find the film in parts or even complete on YouTube. [Here](https://m.youtube.com/watchhttps://m.youtube.com/watch?v=LiP9tbXFOhM) for example is the final scene: the friend of the magician is on stage after a concert (he plays cello) and the magician teleports flowers (corsage) from the audience on the stage.

Comment: Thanks a million, Marzipanherz! This is the film I was looking for!

Comment: @zkvvoob Glad I could help :)